# In a ControlTemplate's trigger, how can I access an element defined in the ControlTemplate's body?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, controltemplate, setter

I have the following (simplified) ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ImageButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type controls:ImageButton}">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
      <Border [StuffRemoved]/>
      <StackPanel [StuffRemoved]>
        <Image [StuffRemoved] />
        <ContentPresenter [StuffRemoved] />
      </StackPanel>      

        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="ImgBtnScale"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        <!-- problem here! -->
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Trigger.Setters>
                <Setter  TargetName="ImgBtnScale" Property="ScaleX" Value="0.9"/>
                <Setter TargetName="ImgBtnScale" Property="ScaleY" Value="0.9"/>
            </Trigger.Setters>
        </Trigger>      


        <!-- rest of the stuff works okay-->

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImgBtnScale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                            To="1.2" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImgBtnScale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                            To="1.2" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>

            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImgBtnScale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                            To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImgBtnScale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                            To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>      
        </Trigger>

    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

It doesn't compile, saying that:

`Cannot find the target 'ImgBtnScale'. (The  target must appear before any Setters, Triggers or Conditions that use it.)`

So how do I access `ImgBtnScale`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access it by name because `ScaleTransform` is not an element in the visual tree, it is just a value of a property of an element (`Grid`).

What you can do instead is to access the property of the transformation via the parent element where it is defined. For example:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" .../>
```

Comment: The bracketed syntax didn't work, but it does seem that using a Storyboard is the way here. By the way, I accomplished my end goal better by using the VisualStateManager instead of Triggers. Anyway, +1 for the visual tree hint.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem, is that ScaleTransform is not a Visual element. So it can`t be found in the VisualTree. You should try to set trigger on the grid and change the whole ScaleTransform.